# WPF ComboBox set SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox, in which I bind my model. I use DataTemplate to display the data

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxShift">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShiftId}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShiftType}"/>                        
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

And bind it with `comboBoxShift.ItemsSource = _db.Shifts.ToList();`, where `_db` is my database context.

From another window I pass `ShiftId`. 
How can I set current item of combobox to display `ShiftType`.

Comment: Besides that you may set `DisplayMemberPath="ShiftType"` instead of the ItemTemplate, you could set `SelectedValuePath="ShiftId"` and then assign or bind `SelectedValue` to the selected id.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your design is a bit flawed. You don't need to use a data template for your purpose, but rather just set the `DisplayMemeberPath`.

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxShift" DisplayMemberPath="ShiftType">
```

Then to select from code

```
comboBoxShift.SelectedItem = My_Shift;
```

Note: If you wanted to get the Shift object from the selected combobox item, here's how you would do that as well.

```
Shift shift = (Shift)comboBoxShift.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are hiding one of the TextBlocks, this will give your desired result:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxShift" DisplayMemberPath="ShiftType">

</ComboBox>
```